# Doctrine Annotation in @var

Tags: doctrine-orm

Base on the documentation, `@var` will be skipped during processing, however, an exception has been thrown in my custom annotation.

```
[Type Error] Attribute "element" of @DisplayProperty declared on property UmEnquiryRequestProposalView::$eventStartDate expects a(n) string|array, but got string.
```

**DisplayProperty**

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("PROPERTY")
 */
class DisplayProperty {
    /**
     * @var string|array 
     */
    public $element = '';
}
```

Also, I have tried to add `@var` into ignore list

```
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('var');
```

But it doesn't work. How can I make it works by keeping `@var`?

Comment: how are you defining the model mapping? If it is via annotation driver, then you need to complete "element" attribute with `@column` definition

Comment: @manix This is not an entity, the `DisplayProperty` is an custom annotation. So I think is nothing to do with `@column` ?